# Безопасность данных

Tags: php, mysql

```
$id_klone = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['kloneid'])));
```

Безопасна ли такая передача данных? И/или лучше как-то это реализовать иначе. Для строк

Comment: переходите на PDO-меньше дыр в безопасности

Answer (score 1):

```
$id_klone = (int) $_POST['kloneid'];
```

При желании можно проверять на <= 0, но после этого преобразования база уже гарантированно не поломается из-за sql-инъекции.